# how to display the name of an array which is inside another array in php

Tags: php

I am new to php and i have a small question.

This is my array

```
$cars=array( "1234"=> array("Toyota","100","2","white"),
            "2468"=> array("Mazda","1000","0","red"),
            "4587"=> array("Mercedes","200","0","green")
                        ); 
$_SESSION['cars']=$cars;
```

the elements 1234, 2468 and 4587 are basically registration numbers of the cars and my task is to insert these registration number in a table.

```
if( isset($_SESSION['cars']))
        {
        foreach($_SESSION['cars'] as $key)
        {?>
                <tr><td><?php echo $key?></td></tr>
```

this is wht i did but it gives me an error saying Notice: Array to string conversion.

can anyone tell me how to do this ? I'll be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['cars'])) {

    foreach($_SESSION['cars'] as $key => $v)
        echo "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td></tr><br />";
}
```

EDIT:

It should work see this example:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $cars = array(
                "1234"=> array("Toyota","100","2","white"),
                "2468"=> array("Mazda","1000","0","red"),
                "4587"=> array("Mercedes","200","0","green")
            ); 

    $_SESSION['cars'] = $cars;

    if( isset($_SESSION['cars'])) {

        foreach($_SESSION['cars'] as $key => $v)
            echo "<tr><td>" . $key . "</td></tr><br />";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
1234
2468
4587
```

Comment: I tried that but it inserted 0 1 and 2 in the registration number column :S i am supposed to insert the whole value "1234" ..any idea wht shld b done ?

Comment: It should work. In case you omitted some code between setting and using $_SESSION['cars'], maybe it does not have the content you expect it to have. You can just easily check it out with var_dump($_SESSION['cars']);

Comment: @Rizier123 okay i am gonna check it out

Comment: @Sasha alryt i'll check that

Comment: @Sasha u r right :O..the values it self are 0 1 2 ...so why is it not storing 1234 as the name of elements of the outer array ?

Comment: @Ashley it should work as you can see in my example! That means your error is somewhere else in the code! (Your changing the array!)

Comment: @Rizier123 yes yes ur code is correct ..the value stored itself is 0 1 2 not "1234", "2468" etc ..do u knw how i save the whole name in the array ?

Comment: @Ashley copy my code and array declaration and also check if your changing the array between the declaration and the echo

Comment: @Ashley Your welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: You can accept answer's how helped you, so other people with the same problem find the answer faster!)

Comment: @Rizier123 thank u ..i have my exam of web designing tomorrow ..i hope it goes well ..umm i actually asked a qts for the first time here ..so i dont exactly understand wht u mean by accepting answer? .

Comment: @Ashley You can go trough this little tour and then you will know it! :D http://stackoverflow.com/tour (takes 1 min or so)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $cars=array( "1234"=> array("Toyota","100","2","white"),
            "2468"=> array("Mazda","1000","0","red"),
            "4587"=> array("Mercedes","200","0","green")
        );
        $_SESSION['cars']=$cars;
        //In separated file
        if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
        if( isset($_SESSION['cars']))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION['cars'] as $key => $value)
            {
                echo "<tr><td> $key </td></tr>";
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Registration 
0   
1   
2

Comment: these r the values i got after writing the above code :S

Comment: @Ashley Try my example, or can you add print_r($_SESSION['cars']);die(); in your code and show me the result?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Toyota [1] => 100 [2] => 2 [3] => white ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Mazda [1] => 1000 [2] => 0 [3] => red ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Mercedes [1] => 200 [2] => 0 [3] => green ) )

Comment: @Ashley, great! now , can you show me the code used to initialize $_SESSION['cars']?

Comment: thanks alot ..but i got the answer now :D ur help is highly appreciated :)